# Ошибка в Gulp. specifier.split is not a function

Tags: gulp, npm, type-error

Выдает ошибку в Gulp'е

> specifier.split is not a function в файле
>   node_modules\resolve\lib\core.js:5

Почему так?
Данный файл не трогал, и не могу понять в чем причина
Прикрепляю код из файла `gulpfile.js`

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'), // Подключаем Gulp
sass         = require('gulp-sass'), //Подключаем Sass пакет,
browserSync  = require('browser-sync'), // Подключаем Browser Sync
concat       = require('gulp-concat'), // Подключаем gulp-concat (для конкатенации файлов)
uglify       = require('gulp-uglifyjs'), // Подключаем gulp-uglifyjs (для сжатия JS)
cssnano      = require('gulp-cssnano'), // Подключаем пакет для минификации CSS
rename       = require('gulp-rename'), // Подключаем библиотеку для переименования файлов
del          = require('del'), // Подключаем библиотеку для удаления файлов и папок
imagemin     = require('gulp-imagemin'), // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с изображениями
pngquant     = require('imagemin-pngquant'), // Подключаем библиотеку для работы с png
cache        = require('gulp-cache'), // Подключаем библиотеку кеширования
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');// Подключаем библиотеку для автоматического добавления префиксов

gulp.task('sass', function(){ // Создаем таск Sass
return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.sass') // Берем источник
.pipe(sass()) // Преобразуем Sass в CSS посредством gulp-sass
.pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%', 'ie 8', 'ie 7'], { 
cascade: true })) // Создаем префиксы
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')) // Выгружаем результата в папку app/css
.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true})) // Обновляем CSS на странице при изменении
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() { // Создаем таск browser-sync
browserSync({ // Выполняем browserSync
server: { // Определяем параметры сервера
    baseDir: 'app' // Директория для сервера - app
},
notify: false // Отключаем уведомления
});
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src([ // Берем все необходимые библиотеки
'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', // Берем jQuery
'app/libs/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js' // Берем Owl.carousel
])
.pipe(concat('libs.min.js')) // Собираем их в кучу в новом файле 
libs.min.js
.pipe(uglify()) // Сжимаем JS файл
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/js')); // Выгружаем в папку app/js
});

gulp.task('css-libs', ['sass'], function() {
return gulp.src('app/css/libs.css') // Выбираем файл для минификации
.pipe(cssnano()) // Сжимаем
.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'})) // Добавляем суффикс .min
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/css')); // Выгружаем в папку app/css
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'css-libs', 'scripts'], function() {
gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']); // Наблюдение за sass файлами в папке sass
gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload); // Наблюдение за HTML файлами в корне проекта
gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);   // Наблюдение за JS файлами в папке js
gulp.watch('app/css/**/*.css', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
return del.sync('dist'); // Удаляем папку dist перед сборкой
});

gulp.task('img', function() {
return gulp.src('app/img/**/*') // Берем все изображения из app
.pipe(cache(imagemin({ // С кешированием
// .pipe(imagemin({ // Сжимаем изображения без кеширования
    interlaced: true,
    progressive: true,
    svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
    use: [pngquant()]
}))/**/)
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img')); // Выгружаем на продакшен
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'img', 'sass', 'scripts'], function() {

var buildCss = gulp.src([ // Переносим библиотеки в продакшен
'app/css/main.css',
'app/css/libs.min.css'
])
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))

var buildFonts = gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*') // Переносим шрифты в продакшен
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))

var buildJs = gulp.src('app/js/**/*') // Переносим скрипты в продакшен
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))

var buildHtml = gulp.src('app/*.html') // Переносим HTML в продакшен
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

});

gulp.task('clear', function (callback) {
return cache.clearAll();
})

gulp.task('npmUpdate', function () {
var update = require('gulp-update')();

gulp.watch('./package.json').on('change', function (file) {
update.write(file);
});

})

gulp.task('default', ['watch'], ['npmUpdate']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не разобрался. Но методом проб и ошибок, правя файл gulpfile.js, в итоге вернув все к изначальному виду, при котором ошибка и возникла, она просто исчезла.
Странная штука этот Gulp. Часто возникают такие вот странные ошибки, баги, не знаю что это, и так же исчезают сами по себе. Мда, вот не уверен, что это хороший ответ, ну какой имею )
Все таки проблема устранена